# Android Volley - HttpResponseCache

Tags: android, caching, httpurlconnection, android-volley

I'm building an Android application which uses Volley to load images from the web.

I'm using an `LruCache` with Volley to cache bitmaps in memory, and this is fine. In addition, I'd like Volley to leverage the built in support for http disk based caching using [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html).

I implemented the example in the given link, but I noticed that nothing is being cached in the `HttpResponseCache` (I checked by sampling the HitCount field in the cache object).

After sniffing around in the Volley source code, I found that Volley manually removes the caching flag when opening a `URLConnection`:

```
private URLConnection openConnection(URL url, Request<?> request) throws IOException {
        URLConnection connection = createConnection(url);

        int timeoutMs = request.getTimeoutMs();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeoutMs);
        connection.setUseCaches(false); // <-- Disables the caching
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        // use caller-provided custom SslSocketFactory, if any, for HTTPS
        if ("https".equals(url.getProtocol()) && mSslSocketFactory != null) {
            ((HttpsURLConnection)connection).setSSLSocketFactory(mSslSocketFactory);
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

You can see this code for yourself here: [Volley - HurlStack](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/c3dea925af9b3523e2e01e8b7799e71ef558c1c5/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HurlStack.java) (line 167)

The moment I comment out this line, the `HttpResponseCahce` works as expected.

My question is: **Why** does Volley disable the UseCaches flag in all `URLConnections`, and what is the risk / side-effects of removing this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am looking at something similar now...